# Releasing window from other window (Qt)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-2012

I work with Qt on VS2012. Part of my code contains intercepting other window (other app) that is working. I managed with intercepting, but when I want to release that window, I can't.
Also when I shut down my app the other window should release and continue to work as a independent app (like it was before intercepting). Now that app is still working (in window task manager the process is still working) but there is no window visible.

Part of my code that allows to intercept other window:

```
void MyApp::setWindow(const QString& name)
{
  WId windowId = (WId) ::FindWindow(0, (TCHAR*)name.utf16());
  if(windowId != NULL)
  {
    childWindow = QWindow::fromWinId(windowId);                //QWindow* childWindow
    childWidget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(childWindow); //QWidget* childWidget
    childWidget->setParent(mainWidget);                        //QWidget* mainwidget = ui.mainWidget;
    childWidget->show();
  }
}
```

I have tried release it by setting parent as 0:

```
childWidget->setParent(0);
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
childWidget->setParent(0);
```

Will not put that window to correct context anyway. You can do it to disengage that foreign window with local process events, though. You should then just close childWidget (likeliest) or transport it somewhere else (unlikely).

```
childWidget.close();
```

Here we may get a run-time error as long as we unaware of other app logic. Normally we don't hijack just any arbitrary window, we do it in some controlled environment e.g. we create Chromium renderer for the given web-page and that web-browser page window is running in the own process and its window is designed to be put in some other context.

An incorrect handling for international wide chars:

As long as you've attempted FindWindow it may resolve to either FindWindowA for accepting ANSI char string or FindWindowW (I believe that is the case) for accepting wide character string and not UTF which implies a different format and not for this API. Matching type of character is not always enough. Wide characters *here* are for the current locale, so spoofing them with UTF-16 may result in the code not finding the window as below. Either of UTF is for transporting international texts between different contexts via Internet or so and for the APIs able to handle them.

```
WId windowId = (WId) ::FindWindow(0, (TCHAR*)name.utf16()); // Don't convert to utf16 here. To WCHAR. toStdWString().c_str() or so
```